# How to ignore "too many parameters" on constructors that use injection

Tags: dependency-injection, sonarlint

If you are using dependency injection it's totally normal that constructors have many parameters.

Is it possible that sonarlint doesn't show the "too many parameters" code smell warning for constructors that use injection?

Comment: DI shouldn't be an excuse for constructors to have many parameters. Too many dependencies probably means that your design doesn't respect [SRA](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Single_responsibility_principle), so SonarLint is right warning you IMHO.

Comment: Like @sp00m, having too many dependency probably means that your service has too many responsibility and that your service should be break into smaller service. Look at the following link to see an example on how to refactor your code : http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/02/RefactoringtoAggregateServices/

Answer (score 6):

In my case a Spring service needed a lot of other services in order to do its work. So rule `squid:S00107` fired and gave me an error in the SonarCube. I found [this article](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/rule-s00107-methods-should-not-have-too-many-parameters-should-consider-lombok-annotations/3181) which proposed to use [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) to work around the issue like so:

**Before:**

```
@Component
public class EventService {

  private final String param1;
  private final String param2;
  private final String param3;
  private final String param4;
  private final String param5;
  private final String param6;
  private final String param7;
  private final String param8;
  private final String param9;

  public EventService(String param1, String param2, String param3, String param4, String param5, String param6, String param7, String param8, String param9) {
    this.param1 = param1;
    this.param2 = param2;
    this.param3 = param3;
    this.param4 = param4;
    this.param5 = param5;
    this.param6 = param6;
    this.param7 = param7;
    this.param8 = param8;
    this.param9 = param9;
  }

  ...
```

**After:**

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class EventService {

  private final String param1;
  private final String param2;
  private final String param3;
  private final String param4;
  private final String param5;
  private final String param6;
  private final String param7;
  private final String param8;
  private final String param9;

  ...
```

Comment: More info at: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-injection-lombok

Answer (score 3):

As other posters noted before, too many arguments for a method or constructor show that somehow the separation of concerns principle has been violated. It is better to go with the following solutions:

- in case of a constructor: a builder pattern
- in case of a method: with a request parameter and a builder if has too many parameters.

This avoids confusion of parameters, i.e. "Was the x, y or the z first argument?"

If all tries fail annotate `@SuppressWarnings("squid:S00107")` on top of the method / constructor you want to ignore. This can only be last resource.

Comment: What if I have lots of `@Autowired` Parameters in a Spring Service constructor? Any options aside of supressing the rule?

Comment: In a Test environment you can use PowerMockito Whitebox.setInternalField(...) method.